# constant load on load sensor

Tags: sensor, load

I heard it is impossible to create scale which will have constant load on it. Is there any workaround, or what type of sensor should I buy?

I need to build a scale which will handle up to 100kg. Constant load on it will be around 60kg but will vary for ~1kg per day. I want to measure this variations every day without manual calibration of putting load off.

Comment: Every load sensor is constantly loaded by a certain amount of force, the question though is how much they can handle permanently, and for that you could consult datasheets.

Comment: Can you help me with this? [link](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Zemic-single-shear-beam-load-cell-L6E-200kg-for-Bench-Scales-NEW/1848488970.html)
What is the name of parameter to handle it permanently?

Answer (score 1):

The zero wanders around with temperature (and time) even with no load, and there's usually a spec for slow drift when a load is constantly applied.

For both those reasons, usually load cells are tared with a known force applied shortly before a measurement is made.

Maybe you could automate the load removal or use a method that has less drift (for example, hydraulic pressure measurement).

Comment: can you tell me the name of the spec for drift so i can compare it with hydraulic sensor? I was looking at this sensor [link](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Zemic-single-shear-beam-load-cell-L6E-200kg-for-Bench-Scales-NEW/1848488970.html)


Is there a way that sensor will get once fully loaded? For me diff from day to day would be enough, so I don't really need exact real value.